# Understanding SPMetal and Linq

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, linq, spmetal

If I generate .cs file using SPMetal for my site and then use it in Visual Studio to develop web part using Linq. And later on I create a new list in my site, will I need to generate .cs file again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer is "Unfortunately, yes, you have to generete .cs files again".**

After changing the list structure you need to regenerate cs files or create custom mapping.

Piece of code from Joerg Krause "[SharePoint 2010 as a Developer Platform](http://books.google.ru/books?id=4lKnn9ZzG1AC&pg=PA233&lpg=PA233&dq=jorg%20krause%20SPMetal&source=bl&ots=LR5tQqoUAr&sig=hP6EQGVudz9mZ0N9jMNq06X90UQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=gGtqUaTBGND14QSiqYDoDQ&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=jorg%20krause%20SPMetal&f=false)" (by the way, it is a very nice book and I advice you to buy and read it if you haven't read it yet):

```
public partial class Book: ICustomMapping
{
    [CustomMapping(Columns=new String[]{"ISBN","UPCA"})]
    public void MapFrom(object listItem)
    {
       SPListItem item=(SPListItem) listItem;
       this.ISBN=item["ISBN"];
       this.UPCA=item["UPCA"];
    }

    public void MapTo(object listItem)
    {
       SPListItem item=(SPListItem) listItem;
       item["ISBN"]=this.ISBN;
       item["UPCA"]=this.UPCA;
    }

    //New property declaratin go here
}
```